inserting multiple array abject data into database using laravel api
I have 2 database called products and product_attributes, and I have link them throught model relationship in Product.php model file. I want to insert multiple array data into my product_attributes database using react js, and am getting error 422 input field required error, but when I test my laravel api it works fine.
ProductController.php file
public function viewProductAttribute($id)
    {
        $product = Product::findorfail($id);
        $productattributes = ProductAttribute::where(['product_id' => $id])->latest()->get();

        return response()->json([
            "productattributes"=>$productattributes,
            "product"=>$product
        ]);
    }

    public function addProductAttribute(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $fields = $request->validate([
            'size' => 'required|max:255',
            'cost_price' => 'required|max:255',
            'sales_price' => 'required',
            'stock' => 'required',
            'sku' => 'required|unique:product_attributes,sku',
        ]);

        $product = Product::select('id','product_name','product_code','product_color','product_cost_price','product_sales_price','product_image')->with('product_attributes')->where(['id' => $id])->first();

        
        $data = $request->all();

        foreach($data['sku'] as $key => $value){
            if(!empty($value)){

                //Prevent SKU duplicate
                $skuCount = ProductAttribute::where('sku',$value)->count();
                if($skuCount>0){
                    return response()->json([
                        "message"=>"SKU Already exist!, Please add a new SKU"
                    ]);
                }

                //Prevent Size duplicate
                $sizeCount = ProductAttribute::where(['product_id'=>$id,'size'=>$data['size'][$key]])->count();
                if($sizeCount>0){
                    return response()->json([
                        "message"=>"Size Already exist!, Please add a new Size"
                    ]);
                }

                $productattribute = new ProductAttribute;
                $productattribute->product_id = $id;
                $productattribute->sku = $value;
                $productattribute->size = $data['size'][$key];
                $productattribute->cost_price = $data['cost_price'][$key];
                $productattribute->sales_price = $data['sales_price'][$key];
                $productattribute->stock = $data['stock'][$key];
                $productattribute->status = 1;
                $productattribute->save();
            }
        }

        return response()->json([
            "productattribute"=>$productattribute,
            "product"=>$product,
            "message"=>"Product Attribute Added Successfully"
        ]);
    }

Product.php Model file
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function product_category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\ProductCategory', 'product_category_id');
    }

    public function product_attributes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ProductAttribute');
    }
}


ViewProductAttributes.jsx file
import { Link, useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import DashboardSidebar from "../DashboardSidebar";
import { AppContext } from "../../Context/AppContext";

export default function ViewProductAttributes() {
    const { id } = useParams();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const { name, token } = useContext(AppContext);
    const [product, setProduct] = useState([]);
    const [productAttributes, setProductAttributes] = useState([]);
    const [productAttributeInput, setProductAttributeInput] = useState([
        {
            size: "",
            sku: "",
            cost_price: "",
            sales_price: "",
            stock: "",
        },
    ]);

    const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});

    async function getProductDetails() {
        const res = await fetch(`/api/view_product_attribute/${id}`, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
        });
        const data = await res.json();

        if (res.ok) {
            setProduct(data.product); //this product is the one comming from ProductController.php @ viewProductAttribute function
        }
    }

    async function getProductAttributes() {
        const res = await fetch(`/api/view_product_attribute/${id}`, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
        });
        const data = await res.json();

        if (res.ok) {
            setProductAttributes(data.productattributes); //this productattributes is the one comming from ProductController.php @ viewProductAttribute function
        }
    }

    const handleAddRows = () => {
        setProductAttributeInput([
            ...productAttributeInput,
            { size: "", sku: "", cost_price: "", sales_price: "", stock: "" },
        ]);
    };

    const handleRemoveRows = (i) => {
        const deleteVal = [...productAttributeInput];
        deleteVal.splice(i, 1);
        setProductAttributeInput(deleteVal);
    };

    const handleChange = (e, i) => {
        const values = [...productAttributeInput];
        values[i][e.target.name] = e.target.value;
        setProductAttributeInput(values);
    };

    async function addProductAttribute(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // console.log("productAttribute", productAttributeInput);

        // const Formdata = {
        //     size: productAttributeInput.size,
        //     sku: productAttributeInput.sku,
        //     cost_price: productAttributeInput.cost_price,
        //     sales_price: productAttributeInput.sales_price,
        //     stock: productAttributeInput.stock,
        // };

        const Formdata = {
            size: "",
            sku: "",
            cost_price: "",
            sales_price: "",
            stock: "",
        };

        const res = await fetch(`/api/add_product_attribute/${id}`, {
            method: "post",
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(Formdata),
        });

        const data = await res.json();

        if (data.errors) {
            setErrors(data.errors);
        } else {
            navigate("/view_products");
            alert(data.message);
        }
    }

    //this useEffect is calling the getProductAttributes function at the top
    useEffect(() => {
        getProductDetails();
        getProductAttributes();
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <div className="xsm:h-[200px] md:h-[220px] w-full bg-primary">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="flex justify-between">
                        <div className="xsm:pt-[20px] md:pt-[50px]">
                            <h1 className="font-roboto text-secondary xsm:text-[30px] md:text-[50px] animation-delay-300 xsm:leading-8 md:leading-[50px]">
                                Modern Courses
                            </h1>
                            <p className="text-white text-[17px] pb-9 xsm:pt-2 md:pt-4">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
                                adipisicing elit. Debitis reiciendis corrupti.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="pt-10">
                <div className="container grid grid-cols-4 gap-6 pt-4 pb-16 items-start">
                    <div className="lg:col-span-3 xsm:col-span-4">
                        <div className="flex items-center mb-3">
                            <Link
                                to="/view_products"
                                className="flex items-center rounded border border-red-600 py-1 px-2 text-white bg-red-600 hover:bg-tertiary hover:border-tertiary"
                            >
                                <i className="fa-light fa-arrow-left mr-1"></i>
                                BACK
                            </Link>
                        </div>
                        <div className="space-y-4">
                            <div className="bg-white p-3 border border-gray-200 rounded">
                                <h1 className="font-roboto text-[25px] text-primary font-semibold capitalize mb-4">
                                    ADD PRODUCT ATTRIBUTE
                                </h1>
                                <div
                                    className="grid xsm:grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-4 gap-4"
                                    key={product.id}
                                >
                                    <div>
                                        <label className="text-gray-600 mb-2 block">
                                            Product
                                            <span className="text-red-600">
                                                *
                                            </span>
                                        </label>
                                        <input
                                            type="text"
                                            className="block w-full border border-gray-300 px-4 py-3 text-gray-600 text-sm rounded placeholder-gray-400 focus:border-primary focus:ring-0"
                                            value={product.product_name}
                                            readOnly
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <label className="text-gray-600 mb-2 block">
                                            Code
                                            <span className="text-red-600">
                                                *
                                            </span>
                                        </label>
                                        <input
                                            type="email"
                                            className="block w-full border border-gray-300 px-4 py-3 text-gray-600 text-sm rounded placeholder-gray-400 focus:border-primary focus:ring-0"
                                            value={product.product_code}
                                            readOnly
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <label className="text-gray-600 mb-2 block">
                                            Cost Price
                                            <span className="text-red-600">
                                                *
                                            </span>
                                        </label>
                                        <input
                                            type="email"
                                            className="block w-full border border-gray-300 px-4 py-3 text-gray-600 text-sm rounded placeholder-gray-400 focus:border-primary focus:ring-0"
                                            value={product.product_cost_price}
                                            readOnly
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <label className="text-gray-600 mb-2 block">
                                            Sales Price
                                            <span className="text-red-600">
                                                *
                                            </span>
                                        </label>
                                        <input
                                            type="text"
                                            className="block w-full border border-gray-300 px-4 py-3 text-gray-600 text-sm rounded placeholder-gray-400 focus:border-primary focus:ring-0"
                                            value={product.product_sales_price}
                                            readOnly
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <button
                                    onClick={handleAddRows}
                                    className="mt-10"
                                >
                                    <i className="fa-light fa-plus pl-1"></i>
                                    Add Rows
                                </button>

                                <form onSubmit={addProductAttribute}>
                                    {productAttributeInput.map((val, i) => (
                                        <div key={i}>
                                            <div className="grid xsm:grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-5 gap-4 py-1">
                                                <div>
                                                    <input
                                                        type="text"
                                                        className="block w-full border border-gray-300 px-4 py-3 text-gray-600 text-sm rounded placeholder-gray-400 focus:border-primary focus:ring-0"
                                                        placeholder="Size"
                                                        name="size"
                                                        value={val.size}
                                                        onChange={(e) =>
                                                            handleChange(e, i)
                                                        }
                                                    />
                                                    {errors.size && (
                                                        <p className="text-red-600">
                                                            {errors.size[0]}
                                                        </p>
                                                    )}
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <input
                                                        type="text"
                                                        className="block w-full border border-gray-300 px-4 py-3 text-gray-600 text-sm rounded placeholder-gray-400 focus:border-primary focus:ring-0"
                                                        placeholder="SKU"
                                                        name="sku"
                                                        value={val.sku}
                                                        onChange={(e) =>
                                                            handleChange(e, i)
                                                        }
                                                    />
                                                    {errors.sku && (
                                                        <p className="text-red-600">
                                                            {errors.sku[0]}
                                                        </p>
                                                    )}
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <input
                                                        type="text"
                                                        className="block w-full border border-gray-300 px-4 py-3 text-gray-600 text-sm rounded placeholder-gray-400 focus:border-primary focus:ring-0"
                                                        placeholder="Cost Price"
                                                        name="cost_price"
                                                        value={val.cost_price}
                                                        onChange={(e) =>
                                                            handleChange(e, i)
                                                        }
                                                    />
                                                    {errors.cost_price && (
                                                        <p className="text-red-600">
                                                            {
                                                                errors
                                                                    .cost_price[0]
                                                            }
                                                        </p>
                                                    )}
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <input
                                                        type="text"
                                                        className="block w-full border border-gray-300 px-4 py-3 text-gray-600 text-sm rounded placeholder-gray-400 focus:border-primary focus:ring-0"
                                                        placeholder="Sales Price"
                                                        name="sales_price"
                                                        value={val.sales_price}
                                                        onChange={(e) =>
                                                            handleChange(e, i)
                                                        }
                                                    />
                                                    {errors.sales_price && (
                                                        <p className="text-red-600">
                                                            {
                                                                errors
                                                                    .sales_price[0]
                                                            }
                                                        </p>
                                                    )}
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="flex">
                                                    <div className="block">
                                                        <input
                                                            type="number"
                                                            min="1"
                                                            className="block w-full border border-gray-300 px-4 py-3 text-gray-600 text-sm rounded placeholder-gray-400 focus:border-primary focus:ring-0"
                                                            placeholder="Stock"
                                                            name="stock"
                                                            value={val.stock}
                                                            onChange={(e) =>
                                                                handleChange(
                                                                    e,
                                                                    i
                                                                )
                                                            }
                                                        />
                                                        {errors.stock && (
                                                            <p className="text-red-600">
                                                                {
                                                                    errors
                                                                        .stock[0]
                                                                }
                                                            </p>
                                                        )}
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div className="flex text-primary gap-2 mt-2">
                                                        {i == 0 ? (
                                                            ""
                                                        ) : (
                                                            <button
                                                                onClick={
                                                                    handleRemoveRows
                                                                }
                                                            >
                                                                <i className="fa-light fa-minus pl-1"></i>
                                                            </button>
                                                        )}
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    ))}
                                    <div class="pt-2">
                                        <button class="bg-primary border border-primary text-white px-8 py-2 mb-3 font-medium rounded text-uppercase flex items-center gap-2 hover:bg-transparent hover:text-primary transition">
                                            ADD
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <table className="w-full text-sm text-left rtl:text-right text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
                                <thead className="text-xs text-gray-500 uppercase bg-gray-50 dark:text-gray-400 border-b-2 border-gray-400">
                                    <tr className="text-nowrap">
                                        <th className="px-3 py-2">ID</th>
                                        <th className="px-3 py-2">
                                            Product ID
                                        </th>
                                        <th className="px-3 py-2">Size</th>
                                        <th className="px-3 py-2">SKU</th>
                                        <th className="px-3 py-2">
                                            Cost Price
                                        </th>
                                        <th className="px-3 py-2">
                                            Sales Price
                                        </th>
                                        <th className="px-3 py-2">Status</th>
                                        <th className="px-3 py-2">Action</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    {productAttributes.length > 0 ? (
                                        productAttributes.map(
                                            (productAttribute) => (
                                                <tr
                                                    key={productAttribute.id}
                                                    className="bg-white border-b dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700"
                                                >
                                                    <td className="px-3 py-2">
                                                        1
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td className="px-3 py-2">
                                                        {
                                                            productAttribute.product_id
                                                        }
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td className="px-3 py-2">
                                                        {productAttribute.size}
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td className="px-3 py-2">
                                                        {productAttribute.sku}
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td className="px-3 py-2">
                                                        {
                                                            productAttribute.cost_price
                                                        }
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td className="px-3 py-2">
                                                        {
                                                            productAttribute.sales_price
                                                        }
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td className="px-3 py-2 text-nowrap">
                                                        {
                                                            productAttribute.status
                                                        }
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td className="px-3 py-2">
                                                        <div className="flex text-center gap-2">
                                                            <button
                                                            // className="hover:text-tertiary"
                                                            // title="Delete"
                                                            // onClick={(e) =>
                                                            //     deleteProductCategory(
                                                            //         e,
                                                            //         productCategory.id
                                                            //     )
                                                            // }
                                                            >
                                                                <i className="fa-light fa-trash"></i>
                                                            </button>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            )
                                        )
                                    ) : (
                                        <p className="py-4 text-red-500 text-[20px]">
                                            No product attributes
                                        </p>
                                    )}
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            {/* pagination */}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="xsm:col-span-4 md:col-span-4 lg:col-span-1 px-4 pb-6 shadow rounded overflow-hidden xsm:mt-10 md:mt-[0px]">
                        <div className="divide-y divide-gray-200 space-y-5">
                            <DashboardSidebar />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}


I know the error is coming from ViewProductAttribute.jsx file in addProductAttribute(e) function at the code below.
// console.log("productAttribute", productAttributeInput);
const Formdata = {
            size: "",
            sku: "",
            cost_price: "",
            sales_price: "",
            stock: "",
        };

Because when I console log productAttributeInput at the above code, I get the inserted data perfectly in my browser console. Please can some one help me on how to insert the data I am getting from console log into my database?
Answer on how to insert multiple array of data in database with react js
